# Text Boxes and Buttons

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner at C# and I'm making this calculator and it has multiple text boxes for different calculations. I've assigned calculator button numbers (0-9) for user input. I can get the number buttons to work for the various textboxes but they are all inputted at the same time. I want to make it so that if a certain textbox is selected, then the user can start using the buttons. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's hard to know what you're doing without seeing what you've tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "they are all inputted at the same time"?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `OnFocus` event of the corresponding `TextBox`. In the method you should set the `Enable` flag of the `Button` instance to `true` where they were originally set to `false`.

Furthermore you need to keep track of which `Textbox` was selected last, and redirect output to that one if the user clicks a `Button`.